# Doctrine multi level inheritance order pblm

Tags: doctrine-orm

When using class table inheritance with multiple levels in doctrine :
Account->User->Dealer
(Dealer inherits from User, User from Account)
Account has the discriminator column and mapping. When persisting a new Dealer entity I get a foreign key error because there is no row in the User table.

So the order in which the insert statements are executed is:
1) Insert into Account
2) Insert into Dealer (which causes the error)
3) insert into User
Can someone help me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your configuration (annotation, yml or xml) of your classes, please?

Answer (score 0):

**this is my configuration :**

```
/**
* @Table(name="Account")
* @Entity
* @InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
* @DiscriminatorMap({"Account" = "Default_Model_Account","User" = "Default_Model_User","Dealer" = "Default_Model_Dealer"})
*/
class Default_Model_Account {
/**
 * @id @column(name="accountID",type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $accountID;
/**
 * @column(name="email",type="string")
 * 
 */
protected $email;
}

/**
* @Table(name="User")
* @Entity
*/
class Default_Model_User extends Default_Model_Account{
/**
 * @column(name="firstName",type="string")
 */
 protected $firstName;

}
```

---

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="Dealer")
* 
*/
class Default_Model_Dealer extends Default_Model_User{
/**
 * @column(name="type",type="string")
 */
protected  $type;
}
```